# Port Forwarding using Nginx for Kafka

Tags: docker, nginx, apache-kafka

I am working on a project where I have Kafka configured as my messaging system.The project has two sides, a backend written in Python which consists of Kafka consumer and producer written using the Confluent-Kafka client, the other side is a machine agent written in Go which uses the Kafka-Go client from SegementIO.Normally Kafka runs under port 9092 and both of my applications runs as expected.The problem I have now is there is certain port restriction in an environment where my machine agent is installed and the only ports opened are 80 and 443.Is there a way to use port forwarding so in my Go client instead of having a URL like *:9092*, I have *80* and this hits the Nginx which in turn should forward it to port 9092.I tried an approach but it did not work out.
The Docker file used is:

```
   ---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:6.2.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:6.2.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"      
   
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092, PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'
  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:6.2.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081
  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.0-6.2.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-6.2.0.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:6.2.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
  ksqldb-server:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-server:6.2.0
    hostname: ksqldb-server
    container_name: ksqldb-server
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      KSQL_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: "broker:29092"
      KSQL_HOST_NAME: ksqldb-server
      KSQL_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8088"
      KSQL_CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING: 0
      KSQL_KSQL_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      KSQL_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      KSQL_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      KSQL_KSQL_CONNECT_URL: "http://connect:8083"
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_TOPIC_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
      KSQL_KSQL_LOGGING_PROCESSING_STREAM_AUTO_CREATE: 'true'
  ksqldb-cli:
    image: confluentinc/cp-ksqldb-cli:6.2.0
    container_name: ksqldb-cli
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    entrypoint: /bin/sh
    tty: true

  ksql-datagen:
    image: confluentinc/ksqldb-examples:6.2.0
    hostname: ksql-datagen
    container_name: ksql-datagen
    depends_on:
      - ksqldb-server
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
    command: "bash -c 'echo Waiting for Kafka to be ready... && \
                       cub kafka-ready -b broker:29092 1 40 && \
                       echo Waiting for Confluent Schema Registry to be ready... && \
                       cub sr-ready schema-registry 8081 40 && \
                       echo Waiting a few seconds for topic creation to finish... && \
                       sleep 11 && \
                       tail -f /dev/null'"
    environment:
      KSQL_CONFIG_DIR: "/etc/ksql"
      STREAMS_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST: schema-registry
      STREAMS_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_PORT: 8081

  rest-proxy:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest:6.2.0
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - 8082:8082
    hostname: rest-proxy
    container_name: rest-proxy
    environment:
      KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: rest-proxy
      KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: "http://0.0.0.0:8082"
      KAFKA_REST_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: 'http://schema-registry:8081'
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    hostname: nginx
    container_name: nginx
    depends_on:
     - broker
         
    volumes:
     - ./kafka_nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    ports:
     - 80:80
```

and the Nginx configuration that I tried is:

```
worker_processes 3;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

stream {
   upstream kafka {
       server broker:9092;
}
   server {
     listen 80;
     proxy_pass kafka;

   }  
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nginx is a web server but the Kafka protocol is not HTTP-based AFAIK… Why don't you just configure Kafka to listen on port 80 directly?

Comment: I tried that option, but the broker would never come up.

Comment: If you really just want to forward a TCP port you could use `socat`.

Comment: Can this be used within the context of Kafka-Go client?

Comment: @slauth Nginx is not a web server. It's a proxy, and can just as easily be configured for TCP/UDP traffic as well as HTTP

Comment: Although I agree, this seems totally unnecessary, what happens when you use `server broker:29092;` since that's the actual port Kafka is running on within the Docker network?

Comment: @OneCricketeer it certainly *is* a web server, but of course you're right in that it is more than that.

Comment: when I did server broker:29092, I get this error broker:29092/1: Failed to resolve 'broker:29092': Temporary failure in name resolution

Comment: Are you sure nginx is on the same network as the broker? Because other containers are using the same name for their `*_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS` properties

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that Kafka is actually running at `server broker:29092`, however, I'm not sure nginx really knows how to handle the Kafka TCP protocol to adequately deal with that request/response; e.g. Kafka is probably going to ack the message to nginx, not your client

---

If you're able to use this in nginx,

```
ports:
    - 80:80
```

Then you should be able to use the same for Kafka

However, you'll need one more change for that to actually work - update the second advertised listener

`PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:80`

Also add to the Kafka container

`KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:80`

Beyond that, whatever controls incoming traffic on 80/443 might only accept HTTP/S traffic , so would therefore drop Kafka TCP connections

In that event, expose the `rest-proxy` container instead on port 80

---

Note that external clients should also be able to reach the Schema Registry and other REST APIs, should you choose to use them, which are actual HTTP traffic, so if you needed to expose those all through the same port, then you can't have nginx serving both a TCP stream and HTTP server at once at that port

Comment: I tried this approach by making the change ports:
      - "80:80"
   
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT,L_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092, PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:80,L_HOST://localhost:9092

Comment: It's not working, so am I missing something.

Comment: You added an extra advertised listener without adding the `KAFKA_LISTENERS` property. You cannot advertise 0.0.0.0 since that's not a routable address

Comment: When you are saying "Beyond that, whatever controls incoming traffic on 80/443 might only accept HTTP/S traffic , so would therefore drop Kafka TCP connections", this means it's not possible to use 80/443 using HTTP/S in the config you described above.And if I enable REST proxy, than all my existing producer and Consumer code will need to modified to support that.

Comment: I don't know anything about your environment, and just making assumptions. Obviously you're running other containers that have bound to other ports on the host, so this "machine agent" you're referring to isn't preventing non 80/443 from being used. Sounds to me like you're instead describing a firewall

Comment: And local clients on your host can still produce and consume to the container, but if you want external machines to interact with the broker, and only inbound HTTP/S traffic is allowed, then, yeah, you'd need to rewrite those clients